# What is the best way to save this? (saving the data generated by an application)

Tags: java, database, file

I have this code, and i want to save the generated data, but i don't know how, A database? a file? do i need to chance everyting in the code and start over again?

I'm from brazil, so the variables and Strings are in portuguese but i guess the way to code is Universal, So any Tips to improve the code will be awesome, i didn't finish yet but it is not a problem.

```
package sistema_academico;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Sistema_Academico
{
    static Aluno Aluno[] = new Aluno[100];
    static Professor Professor[] = new Professor[100];
    static int idA = 0;
    static int idP = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean bSair = true;

            do
            {
                    int nOption = 0;
                    String sEntrada = "";
                    String sConcatenar = "";
                    try
                    {
                     nOption = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("0 - Sair \n" +
                                                    "1 - Cadastrar Aluno \n" +
                                                    "2 - Cadastrar Professor \n" +
                                                    "3 - Pesquisar Aluno \n" +
                                                    "4 - Pesquisar Professor \n" +
                                                    "5 - Alterar Aluno \n" +
                                                    "6 - Alterar Professor \n" +
                                                    "7 - Excluir Aluno \n" +
                                                    "8 - Excluir Professor \n"));
                    }
                    catch(Exception NumberFormat)
                    {

                    }
                     switch (nOption)
                    {           
                    case 1: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastrar Aluno");     
                        sEntrada = "";
                        sConcatenar = "";

                        sEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nome: ") + "_";
                        sConcatenar = sEntrada;

                        sEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Endereço: ") + "_";
                        sConcatenar += sEntrada;

                        sEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Curso: ") + "_";
                        sConcatenar += sEntrada;

                        sEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("RA: ") + "_";
                        sConcatenar += sEntrada;

                        CadastrarAluno(sConcatenar);

                        break;

                    case 2: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastrar Professor");
                        sEntrada = "";
                        sConcatenar = "";

                        sEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nome: ") + "_";
                        sConcatenar = sEntrada;

                        sEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Endereço: ") + "_";
                        sConcatenar += sEntrada;

                        sEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Curso: ") + "_";
                        sConcatenar += sEntrada;

                        sEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Registro: ") + "_";
                        sConcatenar += sEntrada;

                        sEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Materia: ") + "_";
                        sConcatenar += sEntrada;

                        CadastrarProfessor(sConcatenar);                    

                        break;

                    case 3: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pesquisar Aluno");
                        sEntrada = "";

                        sEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Pesquisar RA:");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, PesquisarAluno(sEntrada));


                        break;

                    case 4: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pesquisar Professor");
                        sEntrada = "";

                        sEntrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Pesquisar Registro:");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, PesquisarProfessor(sEntrada));

                        break;

                    case 5: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alterar Aluno");

                        break;

                    case 6: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alterar Professor");

                        break;

                    case 7: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Excluir Aluno");

                        break;

                    case 8: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Excluir Professor");

                        break;

                    case 0:
                        bSair = false;
                        break;

                    default:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opção Invalida");
                        break;
                    }
            }while(bSair);
    }// Metodo Principal



    public static void CadastrarAluno(String Al)
    {   
        idA++;
        String array[] = Al.split("_");
        Aluno[idA] = new Aluno();
        Aluno[idA].setNome(array[0]);
        Aluno[idA].setEndereco(array[1]);       
        Aluno[idA].setCurso(array[2]);
        Aluno[idA].setRA(array[3]);     
    }

    public static void CadastrarProfessor(String Pf)
    {
        idP++;
        String array[] = Pf.split("_");
        Professor[idP] = new Professor();
        Professor[idP].setNome(array[0])    ;
        Professor[idP].setEndereco(array[1]);
        Professor[idP].setCurso(array[2]);
        Professor[idP].setRegistro(array[3]);
        Professor[idP].setMateria(array[4]);
    }



    public static String PesquisarAluno(String RA)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < idA; i++)
        {
            if(Aluno[idA].getRA().equals(RA))
            {
                return Aluno[idA].getNome();
            }
        }
        return "RA não Cadastrado";
    }

    public static String PesquisarProfessor(String RE)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < idP; i++)
        {
            if(Professor[idP].getRegistro().equals(RE))
            {
                return Professor[idP].getNome();
            }
        }
        return "Registro não Cadastrado";
    }

    public static void AlterarAluno(String Al)
    {

    }

    public static void AlterarProfessor(String Pf)
    {

    }

    public static void ExcluirAluno(String Al)
    {

    }

    public static void ExcluirProfessor(String Pf)
    {

    }
}// Classe Principal
```

Comment: please post this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, they are better suited for this type of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you declared all the variables and methods as "static", which can cause serious problem when you try to call the methods in different environment. Make sure they are unique in your case first.

If you want to store all the value generated by your codes, I would recommend to use a database to record all the outputs.

1. Create tables for professors and so on( if you have multiple tables here), attributes like: Name, Course, .... (You know what's left)
2. Create relationships between each of them
3. Use mySQL to insert generated data into relevant tables.

Hope this helps :)